# QGIS model builder: Export model to pyqgis and add some more processing steps

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I have set up a processing model with the QGIS model builder. I want this model now as python script to hardcode some of the inputs (so the client does not have to select dozens of input layers each time the model is started). At the end of the script, I also want to execute some more processing steps, which are not possible in the model builder.
In my case: take the layer "Cables" and "Manholes", throw them in the group "Output", apply .qml styles which are located on the network drive and then export those layers within the Output-group into a specific folder (C:/Temp/Output).

Where do i place my afterprocessing steps into the exported Model.py?
The Model.py ends like this:

```
    # Refactor_Rohre_3
    alg_params = {
        'FIELDS_MAPPING': [{'expression': '"TYPE"','length': 100,'name': 'Typ','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'text'},{'expression': '"VALUE_COLOR"','length': 25,'name': 'Farbe','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'text'},{'expression': '"NAME"','length': 100,'name': 'Label','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'text'},{'expression': '"LR_RESERV"','length': 10,'name': 'FreieRohre','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 4,'type_name': 'int8'},{'expression': ' @b_eigentmer ','length': 50,'name': 'Eigentum','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'text'},{'expression': ' @c_datenbereitsteller ','length': 50,'name': 'Quelle','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'text'},{'expression': ' @d_zweckverband ','length': 50,'name': 'Zv','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'text'},{'expression': ' @e_lagestatus_1vermessen_2_unbekannt_3_ungenau ','length': 50,'name': 'Lq','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'text'},{'expression': ' @f_bemerkung ','length': 100,'name': 'Bem','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'text'}],
        'INPUT': outputs['ExtractByExpression_2']['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': parameters['Com_schutzrohre']
    }
    outputs['Refactor_rohre_3'] = processing.run('native:refactorfields', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
    results['Com_schutzrohre'] = outputs['Refactor_rohre_3']['OUTPUT']

    feedback.setCurrentStep(33)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}


def name(self):
    return 'COM_Kabel'

def displayName(self):
    return 'COM_Kabel'

def group(self):
    return ''

def groupId(self):
    return ''

def createInstance(self):
    return Com_kabel()
```

My afterprocessing script is this:

```
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import *
import os 
names = [layer.name() for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]

# Projektpfad
pathToOutput = QgsProject.instance().absolutePath()+'/Output/'
pathToStyles = QgsProject.instance().absolutePath()+'/Styles/'


# Create Group
root =  QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
mygroup = root.findGroup("Output")
if mygroup == None:
    Output_grp = root.addGroup("Output")
    Output_list = ['COM_Schutzrohre', 'Land_Linie_v1.1', 'Land_Fläche_v1.1', 'COM_Kabel', 'Land_Punkt_v1.1 (COM)' ]
else:
    Output_grp = root.findGroup("Output")
    Output_list = ['COM_Schutzrohre', 'Land_Linie_v1.1', 'Land_Fläche_v1.1', 'COM_Kabel', 'Land_Punkt_v1.1 (COM)' ]

# Move layers into group
layers = qgis.core.QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().layerOrder()
for lyr in layers:
    if lyr.name() in Output_list:
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyr, False)
        root =  QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
        myGroup = root.findGroup("Output")
        myOriginalLayer = root.findLayer(lyr.id())
        parent = myOriginalLayer.parent()
        myLayer = myOriginalLayer.clone()
        myGroup.insertChildNode(-1,myLayer)
        parent.removeChildNode(myOriginalLayer)


#Export Group
layer_list= mygroup.findLayers()
layer_list = [layer.name() for layer in mygroup.children()]
    
for vLayer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if vLayer.name() in layer_list:
        QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat( vLayer,  pathToOutput+ vLayer.name() + ".shp", "utf-8", vLayer.crs(), driverName="ESRI Shapefile" )
layers = qgis.core.QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().layerOrder()

#Style

for lyr in layers:
    basename = lyr.name()        
    lyr.loadNamedStyle(pathToStyles + basename +'.qml')
    lyr.triggerRepaint()
```